# Get list of all registered post types slugs

Tags: custom-post-types, slug, array, post-type

I'd like to get a list (array) of all the post types I registered.

Precisely I would like to retrieve their slugs.

Could someone help me?
thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@EAMann's answer is correct, but there's already a build in WordPress function for fetching all registered post types: `get_post_types`

```
<?php
// hook into init late, so everything is registered
// you can also use get_post_types where ever.  Any time after init is usually fine.
add_action( 'init', 'wpse34410_init', 0, 99 );
function wpse34410_init() 
{
    $types = get_post_types( [], 'objects' );
    foreach ( $types as $type ) {
        if ( isset( $type->rewrite->slug ) ) {
            // you'll probably want to do something else.
            echo $type->rewrite->slug;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **TIP:** You don't need to call `get_post_type_object` if you set the `get_post_types` call to return objects to you, eg. `$types = get_post_types( '', 'objects' );
`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is the following using WordPress function get_post_types();

```
<?php
$get_cpt_args = array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false
);
$post_types = get_post_types( $get_cpt_args, 'object' ); // use 'names' if you want to get only name of the post type.

// see the registered post types
echo '<pre>';
print_r($post_types);
echo '</pre>';

// do something with array
if ( $post_types ) {
    foreach ( $post_types as $cpt_key => $cpt_val ) {
       // do something.
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `register_post_type()`, it adds your new post type to a global variable called `$wp_post_types`.  So you can get a list of all of your post types from that:

```
function get_registered_post_types() {
    global $wp_post_types;

    return array_keys( $wp_post_types );
}
```

The `$wp_post_types` variable is an array that contains your CPT definitions, with each set of CPT arguments (labels, capabilities, etc) mapped to the slug of the CPT.  Calling `array_keys()` will give you an array of the slugs of your CPTs.

Comment: if you look into `wp-includes/post.php` the built-in function `get_post_types()` is returning the same `global $wp_post_types array. why do we create a new function when we already have a built-in function?

Answer (score -1):

A more elegant solution:

```
<?php
$cpt_args = [
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false
];

$type_slugs = array_map( function( $type ) {
    return $type->slug;
}, get_post_types( $cpt_args, 'objects' ) );
```