# How to find a specific post_type using its "rewrite slug"?

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

I've been struggling with a quite specific point.
I registered some custom post types and specified the rewrite slug for each one of them.

```
'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'my-slug' ),
```

But later when i'm trying to use the "rewrite slug" and to find which post_type is requested I cannot use the get_post_type() function : the post_type isn't recognized from the rewrite slug.

```
get_post_type( 'my-slug' )
```

returns

```
bool(false)
```

Does anyone have an elegant solution to find a post_type from its rewrite slug ?

Comment: The slug is the key you registered the post type under (the first argument of `register_post_type`), not the rewrite slug.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? Do you want to check the rewrite slug of the current page you're at to find out which post type it might belong to?

Comment: Yes : my question is definitely to find out which `post_type` a given rewrite slug belongs to ! (in a context where the targeted `post_type` is not available using the `get_queried_object` function).

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I've used for doing this...each with issues:

This one this only works if you've set the rewrite slug for your CPT. if you don't set one it could lead to an error:

```
$post_type = get_queried_object();
echo $post_type->rewrite['slug'];
```

This one will not work on archive pages, because the page type will be "page":

```
$post_type = get_post_type();
if ( $post_type )
{
    $post_type_data = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
    $post_type_slug = $post_type_data->rewrite['slug'];
    echo $post_type_slug;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but has you noticed you sometimes find yourself in a context where the queried object is not what your working on. 
For instance i'm working on a standard page that displays other post types : `www.mydomain.com/my-page/my-custom-post-type-posts`

Comment: So use option 1

Comment: Option 1 does not answer my problem,which is to find a post_type from its "rewrite slug". In option 1 you get the from get_queried_object which is not relevant in my case

Answer (score 0):

I've finally had time to investigate and found a solution (this post helped me : [Get list of all registered post types slugs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34410/get-list-of-all-registered-post-types-slugs)).

From what I know the only to get a Post Type using its rewrite slug is to loop over the registerd post types and compare the rewrite slug with the one requested.

```
$types = get_post_types( ['public'   => true,'_builtin' => false], 'objects' );
foreach ( $types as $type ) {
    if ( isset( $type->rewrite['slug'] ) && 'my-rewrite-slug' == $type->rewrite['slug'] ) {
        $post_type_obj = $type;
        continue;
    }
}
```